# handleChange event listener not working for checkbox component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, event-handling, material-ui

I'm trying to implement a simple checkbox that changes its checked state (true/false) upon clicking. But it does nothing when I click it. For example, upon clicking the checkbox and console logging state.box1 after the click, it's still set to true instead of false. I got the code from Material UI's checkbox example, so I'm confused as to why it doesn't work for me. Any ideas?

```
state = {
  box1: true,
};

handleChange = name => event => {
  setState({ name: event.target.checked });
};

<div>
  <Checkbox
    value="box1"
    checked={state.box1}
    onChange={this.handleChange('box1')}
    label="Primary"
  />
</div>;
```

Comment: It is taking `name` literally. Try wrapping it in square brackets, so that it takes the value 'box1', e.g. `[name]: event.target.checked`

Comment: @George Just tried it. Unfortunately it didn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Checkbox` component passes the event object to the onChange callback.

Your original `handleChange` return a callback function but it does not bind to the component context. So your event object will most likely be `undefined` when you click the checkbox.

you can modify the code to something like this.

```
// takes both the event object and 
handleChange = (event, name) => {
  setState([name]: event.target.checked);
};

<Checkbox
  value="box1"
  checked={state.box1}
  onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, 'box1')}
  label="Primary"
/>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure event is already passed through to the function that handleChange makes in the original code. Although your code is much more readable.